# Warning: "bad storage class" in VS 2012 with templates

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012

I am getting the error when I am building the template code in VS 2012.

```
template<typename T> template<typename Q>
void outer<T>::inner<Q>::iid(explicit T o1,explicit Q o2){

    cout<<"the two template objects are as follows"<<o1<<"    "<<o2<<endl;
    cout << "outer == "<< typeid(T).name() <<endl;
    cout << "inner == "<< typeid(Q).name() <<endl;
    cout << "Full inner == "<< typeid(*this).name() <<endl;

}
```

I am getting this error,

```
nestedtemplate.h(17): warning C4042: 'o1' : has bad storage class
nestedtemplate.h(17): warning C4042: 'o2' : has bad storage class
```

Any reason why I am getting this error. this code build without any error in VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `explicit` keyword for function arguments like this. Changing the signature to

```
template<typename T> template<typename Q>
void outer<T>::inner<Q>::iid(T o1, Q o2)
```

will fix the error.

The `explicit` keyword is used on single-argument constructors (and, in C++11, conversion operators) to specify that the compiler should not automatically perform conversions, but only do so when the programmer explicitly specifies that it should. It's useful (I would go so far as to say recommended) to avoid strange errors creeping into your code.

I'm not sure what exactly you were trying to do by using `explicit` as you did -- can you give us more details so we can suggest a legal alternative?

Comment: Hi Tristan, but how this is able to complile warning free in VS2008? also I am using this keyword, coz I dont want to have any implicit conversion between data types, passed as a parameter.

Comment: I don't know about VS2008... possibly it was a non-standard extension, or possibly it just didn't generate a diagnostic when it should have. To avoid implicit conversions, you need to ensure that whatever types you use as `T` and `Q` don't have any non-`explicit` single-argument constructors.

Comment: One more question, is there any limitations while defining template classes w.r.t the compilations unit. my problem is that I am getting error when defining the member template function in another translation unit.